# My machine has no hostname "Failed to start hostname.service: Unit hostname.service is masked."

Tags: kali-linux, services, hostname, umask

I was trying to change the hostname on my machine according to this article: `https://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/12/12/change-hostname-kali-linux/`

When I got to the part

```
service hostname.sh stop
sleep 1
service hostname.sh start
```

The hostname will stop correctly it seems, but I can't get it to start. Now, whenever I scan my IP from a secondary machine, my hostname appears as n/a.

When I try to start the hostname, it will say

```
Failed to start hostname.service: Unit hostname.service is masked.
```

I've done some research on the topic and I tried the command

```
systemctl unmask hostname.service
```

as well as

```
systemctl unmask hostname
```

These execute without error.

When I try any of these commands however, I get the same error again about it being masked.

```
systemctl enable hostname.service
systemctl enable hostname
systemctl start hostname.service
systemctl start hostname
start hostname.service
start hostname
```

Lastly, I even tried to mask it and then unmask it again, with the same result.
These symptoms persist through multiple reboots as well. I would greatly appreciate any help as I am quite stumped.

Also, for what it is worth, I am using Kali Linux a Debian distribution.

UPDATE

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    kali.net     VVTOETSC
#The following lines are desirble for IPV6 capable hosts
::1    localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/hostname

```
VVTOETSC
```

Comment: What is in /etc/hostname ? What is in /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article referenced in your question dates back to 2013 and is outdated. To change hostname simply do the following:

- Disconnect from the network
- Run the command `hostname new_hostname` as root.
- Connect back to the network

Answer (score 0):

- Try to boot in Advanced Mode
- Insert root password
- Try to find any file which has significantly huge size e.g. video, that you think when you delete it, it wont affect you whatsoever. You can always check the file sizes by typing ls -S or ls --size
- Delete that file then reboot. It should work after that.
- If it hasnt you got to find another file and test reboot until it works.

The reason for this problem is that there's no enough space in booting partition to load those failed service. Simple solution is to remove extraordinary huge file. Then boooom... it will work..

Comment: What evidence do you see of a full filesystem?

Comment: You're a f*ckin GENIOUS!!! Thanks brother! I couldn't figure out what the problem was. You saved me from a probable freak out :)